# Big-endian byte to Int in java

Tags: python, java, byte, protocols, endianness

I have this server-client protocol in my project and in the first byte of the message there is the message code (<MsgCode><MsgLength><Msg>).

```
response += data_length.to_bytes(k_MESSAGE_DATA_LENGTH_BYTES, "big")
response += response_message.encode()
response += '\n'.encode()
client_socket.sendall(response)
```

(message_code = 202 and k_MESSAGE_CODES_BYTES = 1)

However, at my client (written in Java - for android):

```
private BufferedReader m_input;
...
String line = m_input.readLine();
int code = line.charAt(0);
```

The code is - '�' 65533

How can I get the code 202 and not this strange value?

Saw that in Python the response looks like this: b'\xca'

However, couldn't understand why in Java the value is so different.
Tried to look up a solution but couldn't find.

Comment: Java uses a weird form of modified UTF-16 encoding for strings so if the binary representation matters don't attempt to parse the string representation. Its technically possible, but it will be way more effort than it is worth to get working the way you expect. I would avoid `String` or `char[]` in general in favor of using `byte[]` or some form of byte buffer instead.

Comment: You are reading the value as characters instead of as bytes. You should not consider it text when it is actually binary. `BufferedReader` reads the input as characters in the system's character encoding.